# When "someone makes X dollars a year in the US", is that gross or net income?

Tags: united-states, income

I often hear/read the phrase "makes X dollars a year". Could you elaborate what this means?

So, for instance, if someone makes 45 thousand a year (in the United States), how large is his monthly net pay?

Answer (score 11):

That's gross income. So the $45,000 a year would translate into $3750 a month BEFORE taxes. (That's also before the more than 8% employee's Social Security and Medicare taxes, which "come off the top.")

In a sense, there is the potential for confusion. Corporate earnings are stated AFTER taxes. But personal earnings are stated BEFORE.

Comment: What about public sector earnings?

Comment: public sector earnings are stated in red ink or between parenthesis.